# Using a Queue as datasource

Tags: c#, data-binding

I would like to display items from a `Queue` in a Gridview in Windows Forms. I can set the datasource attribute of the Gridview to the `Queue`, but it won't be *automatically* updated. I know I can use the `BindingList` class, but then I lose my `Queue` functionality.

Is there any way to combine the two classes, or do I have to implement one of the behaviours in a derived class?

What I'm doing is processing a list of items, I want to show the remaining ones in a grid. The data should not be changed by the user, but I want the GridView to be updated as the contents of the Queue change.

Example:

In form:

```
Proccessor pro = new Processor();
gridview.DataSource = pro.Items;
```

In class:

```
class Proccessor {
    Queue<DataBlock> _queue = new Queue();

    public Queue<DataBlock> Items  { 
        get { 
            return _queue;
        }
    }

    public void AutoProcess() {
        while (_queue.Count > 0) {
            Process(_queue.Dequeue());
        }
    }

    private void Process(DataBlock db) { ... }
}
```

Comment: After misunderstanding the question twice myself, I thought I'd take a stab at clarifying what it is you're after. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would subclass Queue as QueueForDisplay. The constructor would take a view control. I would override the Enqueue and Dequeue methods. In those overrides, I would update the view control. If you don't like the tight coupling, you could simply subclass Queue as QueueWithEvents and provide OnEnqueue and OnDequeue events.

Answer (score 2):

The whole purpose of a Queue is that entries can only be added in one place. So the idea of binding this to a UI grid so it can be updated is, uh, interesting - how should the UI look?

You'll definitely have to consider your own custom collection, or as you say, derive from BindingList and handle e.g. CancelNew accordingly. See the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx) for details.